# Void loop not looping properly

Tags: arduino-uno

so I'm creating a traffic light system on an arduino uno. my current issue is that my main loop isn't working. it is supposed to go through regular mode which makes each light turn on for one second then the next and so on. currently all that happens is that it does one rotation of regular mode then stays stuck on red.ive kept the rest of the code on here just incase its somthing elsewere thats causing the issue.

```
//light variables
int red = 10;
int yellow = 9;
int green = 8;

int inches = 0;
int cm = 0;
float distance;

String inString = "";
int button = 2;
int ECHOPIN = 6;
int TRIGPIN = 7;
int BUZZER = 12;
int sensorPin = A0;            
unsigned int sensorValue = 0;  
char inVal;
int darkness = 150;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);//red led
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);//yellow led
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);//green led
  pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);//rangefinder input
  pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);//rangefiner output
  pinMode(BUZZER,OUTPUT);//buzzer
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200); 


}

void loop(){
  distance = distancefind();
  sensorValue = LDRfind();
  if(sensorValue < darkness)
  {
    nightMode();
  }
  else if(distance < 10)
  {
    pedestrianMode();
  }
  else
  {
   regularMode();
  }
}




void regularMode(){ 
    // Green + yellow off. Red on for 2 seconds
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    delay(2000);

    // Green + red off. Yellow on for 1 second
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    delay(1000);

    // Red + yellow off. Green on for 2 seconds 
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
    delay(2000);

    // Red + green off. Yellow on for 1 second
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    delay(1000);

}

void pedestrianMode(){
  // buzzer buzzes. yellow bulb flashes for 10 seconds.

  for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
        digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
        delay(200);
 } 
}

void nightMode(){
 digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
 digitalWrite(green, LOW);
 digitalWrite(red, HIGH);

  if(distance <10){
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  }
  else{
    nightMode();

  }
}

float distancefind(){
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,LOW); 
 distance = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH); // return 0 if no high pulse in 1sec
 distance = distance/58;
 Serial.print(distance);
 return distance;
}

int LDRfind(){
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  Serial.println("Sensor value: ");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  return sensorValue;
}

void buttonPress(){
  if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH){
        delay(15); // software debounce
        if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
            // if the switch is HIGH, ie. pushed down - change the lights!
            digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
            delay(15000); // wait for 15 seconds
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so before posting this i had been playing around for a good hour. the minuite after posting this i had an idea that the constant red was from my night mode. ive added some distance checking and it works fine. sorry to have wasted whoever is looking time.